# How to completely remove "\n" in text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-files

So the text file I have is formatted something like this:

```
a

b

c
```

I know how to `strip()` and `rstrip()` but I want to get rid of the empty lines. 
I want to make it shorter like this:

```
a 
b
c
```

Comment: Skip blank lines: `if line == '\n': continue`

Comment: Do you just want to remove \n? Do you want to preserve spaces?

Comment: I don't want to preserve the spaces.

Comment: Then you'd get `abc`, not three lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could remove all blank lines (lines that contain only whitespace) from stdin and/or files given at the command line using [`fileinput` module](http://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input(inplace=True):
    if line.strip(): # preserve non-blank lines
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions :

```
import re

txt = """a

b

c"""

print re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', txt) # replace one or more consecutive \n by a single one
```

However, lines with spaces won't be removed. A better solution is :

```
re.sub(r'(\n[ \t]*)+', '\n', txt)
```

This way, wou will also remove leading spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove any line that only equals "\n":

```
in_filename = 'in_example.txt'
out_filename = 'out_example.txt'

with open(in_filename) as infile, open(out_filename, "w") as outfile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if line != "\n":
            outfile.write(line)
```

If you want to simply update the same file, close and reopen it to overwrite it with the new data:

```
filename = 'in_example.txt'
filedata = ""

with open(filename, "r") as infile:
    for line in infile.readlines():
        if line != "\n":
            filedata += line

with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(filedata)
```